# Filling down a column with a range/length relative to another column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I'm trying to fill a column down with a specific value.

I used the xlDown function, which crashed Excel.

I want the cells of column B to be filled *only* as long as the cells in column A aren't empty.

My idea was to declare a variable and initialize it with the value of the length of any other column, then set that variable as the end of the range.

I think using a loop would be a better alternative.

```vb
Sub fillColumn()

Dim myrange as Range
Set myrange = Columns(1)

For Each cell In myrange.Cells
    Do While cell <> vbNullString
        Cell.Offset(0,1).Value = "Yes"
    Next
Loop

End Sub()
```

I can't figure out how to handle `do-while` loops in conjunction with `for` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use the next way, not needing any iteration:

```
Sub fillBforNotEmptyA()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngA As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
   Set rngA = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)                 'the reference range
   
   sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value2 = sh.Evaluate("IF(" & _
                    rngA.address & "<>"""",""Yes"","""")")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly, It's the first time I see the Evaluate function, I'll check it out :)

Comment: Side note:+) Given a fully qualified setting of sh a [worksheet related evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) via `sh.Evaluate(...)` guarantees a fully qualified range reference, whereas an unprefixed `Evaluate(...)` would need more detailed range indications like e.g. `Sheet1!A2:A100` or a further textual insertion of `rngA.Address(External:=True)` to the formula string to be evaluated. @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Yes, it is better, especially because I wrote a comment (`'use here the sheet you need`) and evaluation, as it is in my code, it is done for/on the active sheet. I also wrote, but I could never proved it, that using `sheet.Evaluate` may be faster than `Application`.Evaluate`... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- find first row within specific column
- find last row within specific column

  ```
  for i = firstrow to lastrow
    if cells(i, yourColumn).value2 <> vbnullstring then
       cells(i, yourColumn+1).value2="yes"
    end if
  next i
  ```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but how do I define `firstrow` and `lastrow`? Those aren't reserved words AFAIK?